# Deserialize JSON to type containing reference to another deserialized object in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a following model:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class EntityParent : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public EntityChild EntityChild { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public EntityParent(string id, EntityChild entityChild)
    {
        Id = id;
        EntityChild = entityChild;
    }
}

public class EntityChild : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public int Age { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public EntityChild(string id, int age)
    {
        Id = id;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Next I have some JSON that I need to deserialize to collections of the above types:

```
{
            "Children":
            [
                {
                    "Id"          : "Billy",
                    "Age"         : 42
                }
            ],

            "Parents" :
            [
                {
                    "Id"          : "William",
                    "EntityChild" : "Billy"
                }
            ]
}
```

Eventually I want to have a list of `EntityChild`ren and a list of `EntityParent`s that will (optionally) contain references to objects in the first list , or at least references to instances of `EntityChild`. I have attempted to write a custom `JsonConverter` (I am using **Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1** NuGet package), where in the `ReadJson()` method I am looking for a child with specific `Id`, like so:

```
public class ParentConverter<TEntity> : JsonConverter where TEntity : IEntity
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TEntity> _children;

    public ParentConverter(IEnumerable<TEntity> children)
    {
        _children = children;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        TEntity target = _children.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == jObject["Id"].ToString());

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(TEntity).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here's a simple test:

```
public class JsonTest
{
    const string Json = @"
        {
            ""Children"": [
                {
                    ""Id""          : ""Billy"",
                    ""Age""         : 42
                }
            ],

            ""Parents"" : [
                {
                    ""Id""          : ""William"",
                    ""EntityChild"" : ""Billy""
                }
            ]
        }";

    public static void Main()
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Json);
        var children =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntityChild>>(jObject["Children"].ToString());
        var parents =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntityParent>>(jObject["Parents"].ToString(),
                new ParentConverter<EntityChild>(children));
    }
}
```

`children` are deserialized properly, but `parents` throw a `JsonReaderException` when attempting to call `JObject.Load(reader);` in `ReadJson()`, saying "*Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '[0].EntityChild'.*"

Does anyone know how I should go about it? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Updated the `EntityChild` with extra property to emphasize that the property on `EntityParent` has to be of `EntityChild` type, and **not a string**.

Comment: Who designed that JSON structure? That is very odd

Comment: @SirRufo Unfortunately it's out of my hands :(, and it wasn't me ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is sort of a workaround using LINQ, where I basically join the parent JObjects with children JObjects to build the parent and the child:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Json);

        IEnumerable<EntityParent> parents =
            from parent in jObject["Parents"]
            join child in jObject["Children"] on parent["EntityChild"] equals child["Id"]
            select
                new EntityParent(
                    parent["Id"].ToString(),
                    new EntityChild(
                        child["Id"].ToString(),
                        child["Age"].ToObject<int>()));
    }
```

If children list would exist already, then the join could be performed on that list instead, like so:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Json);

        var children =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntityChild>>(jObject["Children"].ToString());

        IEnumerable<EntityParent> parents =
            from parent in jObject["Parents"]
            join child in children on parent["EntityChild"] equals child.Id
            select new EntityParent(parent["Id"].ToString(), child);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Entity parent should be as below:

```
public class EntityParent : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public string EntityChild { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public EntityParent(string id, string entityChild)
    {
        Id = id;
        EntityChild = entityChild;
    }
}
```

And in `main()` change as below:

```
var parents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntityParent>>(jObject["Parents"].ToString());
```

and it works.

Comment: Yes, but the point is to have a property of type EntityChild, so in the model I can use self defined types instead of strings. The example is intentionally simple but in the real scenario I would have other properties on EntityChild aside from Id, and then this solution would not be sufficient.